# Split categorical image into multi-band image in Google Earth Engine, where every band only contains pixels from one category

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, masking, multi-band

**Context**

I need to calculate the yearly forest area lost for every country, based on the Hansen Tree Cover Loss (TCL) image. The band I use is categorical and indicates the lossyear in the form of an integer (e.g. a pixel that was deforested in 2005 would show the value 5). I identified 3 steps to reach my goal:

1. Mask the TCL layer with every year
2. Calculate the pixel area of pixel that were deforested in a certain year
3. Sum up the calculated pixel areas on a country level

I am looking for a simple way to tackle step 1: Splitting the lossyear band of the TCL layer into separate bands, where every band contains only pixel of a certain year (e.g. 1 band with only pixels with the value one, ..., one band with only pixels of year 21).

**What I tired**

The code tackling steps 1 and 2 outlined above (aggregation to country needs to be added in the form of ReduceRegions and applied to every year).

```
var lossyears = ee.List.sequence(1, 21)
var gfw_tcl = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2021_v1_9")

//////////////////////// FUNCTIONS ////////////////////////

// Mask TCL image with year value and turn that value to 1 to be
// subsequently multiplied with the area, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359852/how-do-i-extract-pixels-of-specific-values-from-a-raster-in-google-earth-engine
var maskYear = function(year) {
  var gfw_tcl_lossyear = gfw_tcl.select('lossyear')
  return gfw_tcl_lossyear.updateMask(
  gfw_tcl_lossyear
  .eq(year))
  .remap({from: [year], to: [1], bandName: 'lossyear'})
  .rename('forestloss');
};


// Calculate area of pixels in image in hectares [ha]
var pixelArea = function(image) {
  return image.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000);
};


// Calculate area deforested in ha [ha]
var yearlyAreaDeforested = function(year) {
  var yearTCL = maskYear(year);
  return pixelArea(yearTCL);
};


//////////////////////// MAIN ////////////////////////

var yad = lossyears.map(yearlyAreaDeforested);
```

The code yields the following error: List (Error) Image.eq, argument 'image2': Invalid type. Expected type: Image. Actual type: Float. Actual value: 1.0

**The question**

How can I achieve splitting a categorical image into bands where every band contains only values from one category, without a for-loop?

I am also open to different approaches if what I try to do does not make sense within the strict division of client-server side in Google Earth Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you just need to cast the number that comes into your mapped function into an Image (because it's too late for the client to figure that out for you.

```
var maskYear = function(year) {
  var gfw_tcl_lossyear = gfw_tcl.select('lossyear')
  return gfw_tcl_lossyear.updateMask(
  gfw_tcl_lossyear
  .eq(ee.Image.constant(year)))
  .remap({from: [year], to: [1], bandName: 'lossyear'})
  .rename('forestloss');
};
```

But you can do it all in one go with this:

```
maskYear = gfw_tcl.select("lossyear").eq(ee.Image.constant(lossyears))
```

Each band of that image will be 1 for the given year, and 0 everywhere else.
You can multiply that with the pixelArea image directly (or you can self-mask it if you want the 0s to go away for some reason).